# Two Actions from one action PHP-Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I have two actions need to run at a time from one controller. first thing pdf download(force download),and show simple thank you message.these two actions are working fine. but when I placed in action only one action is  successfully executed.but I want two actions executed with only one button/link.

```
public function actionThankYou()
{
    $this->actionPdf(); //action
    $this->render('thankyou'); // rendering thankyou view page
}
```

view:

```
 echo CHtml::link('Save & Submit',array('EjfoOrgRecruiting/thankYou'));
```

am I following correct procedure or not? suggest me best way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this..

```
    public function actionThankyou()
{
    $this->render("thankyou");
}
```

in the thankyou view  I wrote to refresh page after 2 secs. like this

```
header('Refresh:2;url='. $this->createUrl('site/pdf'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
public function actionThankYou()
{
$this->pdf(); //action
$this->render('thankyou'); // rendering thankyou view page
}

 protected function pdf() {
 // your code 
 return $result;
 }
```

OR use one action for pdf download and thank you message.
example,

```
 public function actionThankYou()
{
// code for pdf download
$this->render('thankyou'); // rendering thankyou view page
}
```

Comment: already tried that one also. pdf is downloading but not showing thankyou message.

Comment: $mPdf->Output('something.pdf','D');  //pdf output

after this line no code will executed. if I put echo befor pdf output it showing "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by" error

Comment: Please check any blank line will occur during starting of view page or controller and model. This error is because of that.